# Display the last value in a data sheet of duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of duplicate values and I need to display the last value in the data sheet.

In the example below I need to display that the *code* `ER16` has a *qtyleft* (quantity left) of 4

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

To return the last non-blank entry in column A:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A<>""),A:A)
```

To return the corresponding entry in column B:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A:$A<>""),B:B)
```

Explanation:  `$A:$A<> ""` returns an array of `TRUE` or `FALSE`
  `1/...`  converts that to an array of `1`'s and `DIV/0`'s.

`LOOKUP(2,...`  Since there is no value of 2, `LOOKUP` will return the index of the last value that is less than 2.  Because of the formula, this will be the last `1` which is the index to the last entry in column A
  The result vector tells us to return that value from either column A, for the code, or column B for qtyleft.